# jQuery Plugins are using deprecated feature of jQuery v3.5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

We are migrating from jQuery v1.12.4 to v3.5.1. I have updated our codebase by removing the deprecated features. But I found several plugins that use some deprecated features like - jQuery.isNumeric(), jQuery.type(), jQuery.trim(), these are causing warnings (Because of jQuery Migrate) in the console saying - These features are deprecated.

I found the latest versions of these plugins. Unfortunately, the latest ones are also using the same deprecated functions.

What should be the next step on this?
Should I use jQuery Migrate (Production version) at the production deployment time or jQuery v3.5.1 will automatically take care of this ?

Comment: well, yeah.. why not?

Comment: If you check this URL, https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/
It says we need to remove the jQuery Migrate and keep the codebase running on jQuery v3.5.1 code only